# PhoneGap - App Not Installed An existing package by the same name with a conflicting signature in already installed

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build, phonegap, phonegap-cli

I have build an app v1.0.4 using phonegap cli-6.5.0 , while updating this version with my previous version v1.0.3 it show the error App Not Installed An existing package by the same name with a conflicting signature in already installed

I have used the correct  keystore file which i was used for previous build , I don't know how to solve this issue, I have attached my config file

[config.xml](http://drive.google.com/file/d/1DpGp-kAjwuWGyWiDG_YVD_537bJObrgo/view)

Answer (score 0):

Simply first uninstall the prevous application from device/emulator then reinstall apk with new signature on device/emulator.

Conflict happend because you altready have installed one app on your device with same name and different signature (the old one).

Comment: I have tried Its working fine.  but I need to update my previous app with new app.Because i have to update this apk in play store.

Comment: You need to build in RELEASE version with same android keystore of released app. I think you build in DEBUG with debug keystore, and this are changed in new version of phonegap. Please double check your build target and signature settings.

Comment: I have build using same android keystore of released app i have checked several times.